# An entire function whose only zeros are positive integer

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, entire-functions

This is a problem from my past Qual: "Prove or disapprove. There is an entire function $f$ s.t. $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and nonzero elsewhere."

For this type of problems, I think of Identity Theorem. $f(n)=0$ for all $n$ and hence the set $\{z|f(z)=0 \}$ has an accumulation point ($\infty$), so $f=0$ and hence there is no such function.

However, I suppose $\infty$ does not count as an accumulation point? Am I right and if not, how should I solve this?

Comment: Try with $\sin(\pi z)$, here $f$ is not analytic nor meromorphic at $\infty$ (ie. $f(1/z)$ is not analytic nor meromorphic at $0$) so no $\infty$ isn't an accumulation point **inside the domain of analyticity/meromorphicity**. There is a way to make the product $\prod_n (1-z/n)$ converge by adding an $\exp(z/n)$ term.

Comment: But $\sin(\pi z)$ are zero when $z$ is negative integer. SO I suppose this function is not correct?

Comment: $\sin(\pi z)$ was just an example showing that an "accumulation point at $\infty$" is not a barrier. For a specific function you could take $1/\Gamma(1-s)$, or construct one from scratch.

Comment: i see. THank you

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)}$ will do if you allow $n=0$ as a zero, a translation by $1$ of that if you start at $n=1$